# How to generate n edges each between m nodes

Tags: graph, nodes, edges

I'm having trouble conceptualizing my problem. But essentially if I have m nodes, and want to generate no more than n connections for each node. I also want to ensure that there is a always a path from each node to any other node. I don't care about cycles.

I don't have the proper vocabulary to find this problem already existing though I'm sure it has to exist somewhere.

Does anyone know of a place where this problem is explained, or know the answer themselves?

Comment: Is the graph directed? Is there a minimum number of edges, other than the `m-1` edges required to make the graph connected?

Comment: Will there be a possibility of an invalid case,  like n = 5 and m = 2. Then there can be no graph possible.

Comment: The graph is not directed all edges are 2 way paths between the nodes. And no, no minimum number of edges beyond 1 since we are not allowed to have any disconnected nodes, and all nodes must have a path to all others. @beaker

Comment: No there is no possibility of n=5 and m=2. We cannot have more edges than nodes - 1. @zenwraight

Comment: Got it, let me ask some more questions to get a clear idea. Can you provide a sample input and sample output if possible. Also each node cannot have more than n connections doesn't it mean they should have exactly n connections or they can have less than n connections also if possible ?

Comment: @zenwraight as the number of nodes may not be divisible by the maximum number of edges they we must by necessity allow less than n but greater than 1. For example if we have 49 nodes and we want all nodes to have 7 edges then it's possible but if we have 52 nodes and we want all nodes to have 7 edges we run out of nodes for the final 3 edges. That's the reason for the maximum definition, not exact definition. Example input would be 4 nodes with 2 max edges each, 1 each would be invalid in this case because it would result in disconnected nodes. Nodes A, B, C, and D have edges AB, AC, CD, BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to construct a Spanning Tree to ensure that all nodes are connected, then add edges that don't violate the maximum number of edges per node until you have the target number of them. In pseudocode:

```
// nodes[] is a list of all m nodes in our graph
connected_nodes = nodes[0];
// add nodes one by one until all are in the spanning tree
for next_node = 1 to (m-1)
   repeat
      select node connected_nodes[k]   // randomly, nearest, smallest degree, whatever
   until degree(k) < n   // make sure node to connect to does not violate max degree
   add edge between nodes[next_node] and new node connected_nodes[k]
   add nodes[next_node] to connected_nodes[]
end for

// the graph is now connected, add the desired number of edges
for e = m+1 to desired_edge_count
   select 2 nodes i,j from connected_nodes, each with degree < n
   add edge between nodes i and j
end for
```

Comment: This does solve my problem, but I think it can be improved on by tracking nodes as you create them, and adding the first n-1 nodes to each node created. Then removing the nodes from the tracking queue as they hit n edges. this would result in an even distribution of edges until they very end, and not have any unconnected nodes.

That way I don't have to loop through all nodes a minimum of twice.

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of improvements you could make. The main purpose is to use the spanning tree to ensure connectivity. If you remove nodes from the `connected_nodes` list when they reach `n` connections, you'll only have to perform a number of iterations equal to the number of desired edges.